What would happen if the king was incapacitated?
If a Jewish king became incapacitated, for instance if he was in a coma, what would happen? Would a new king be appointed? Would nothing happen and the people would simply wait? Would the queen, or son or other person be given temporary authority to rule?

https://www.sefaria.org/II_Kings.15.5

@DoubleAA the king in this case was still mentally capable. If he was in a coma then you couldn't communicate with him, perhaps it would be different.
